# Dyanmodb use arithmetic in update condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb update expression and I would like to validate if a sum of fields values is greather than other value, something like this:

`.withConditionExpression("#a + #b >= :myValue")`

Like this Dynamodb returns an error. Is there a way to atomically validate that condition?

Answer (score 3):

According to AWS Docs on [Expressions Operators And Functions Syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax)

Operands of the comparison operation can be only *primitive* field names (**CANNOT be arithmetical expressions as in your question**).

Documentation says:

> In [...Condition expression...], an operand can be the following:
>
> - A top-level attribute name, such as Id, Title, Description or ProductCategory
> - A document path that references a nested attribute